# Removing empty elements from dictionary

Tags: python

I would need to remove empty elements from this data

```json
{'history': [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11'], 'what': [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11'], '5': ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5']}
```

printed by the following:

```
print({ k : v for k, v in result.items()  })
```

I have tried with

```
print({ k : v for k, v in result.items() if v and v[0] })
```

but it removes also some elements which does not contain empty elements.

Comment: Just a note: `print({ k: v for k, v in result.items() })` is the same as `print(result)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
result = {k: list(filter(None, v)) for k, v in result.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in your_dict.keys():
    new_list = []

    for element in your_dict[key]:

        if element != []:
            new_list.append(element)

    your_dict[key] = new_list.copy()
```

You check all key,value pairs, start by initializing a new list, append to the list if the empty item is not present, then you set the value of your_dict[key] to be this new list.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine. It ignores the [] inside of each sublist

```
for item in items:
    print([x for x in items[item] if x != []])
```

outputed:

```
['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11']
['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11']
['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension like so:

```
print({k: [item for item in v if len(item)] for k, v in result.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'history': ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11'], 'what': ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11'], '5': ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5']}
```